# TypeScript: Why type conditions behave differently in generic types?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

In TypeScript, I'd assume that

```
type X = A extends B ? true : false
```

Would be equal to:

```
type Check<P, Q> = P extends Q ? true : false
type Y = Check<A, B>
```

[But as it turns out](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDOwBOBLAdgcygHykwFcBbAIwlQChRIoAhBQ0i626AYSZQxygDJm5SlRrhoADSZwIAD2ARMAEyQMoAfihoi0AFxQAZgEMANkghi6HABYQAxgGsAPAAUANFACKAPiYuocgrKqp4aWqg6UPrGZhbsUACaTDb2zjAe9N6W0ABayQHyiipqmtp6hqbm2VAA6sm2jk4cGVlUAPRtWtboqj1QAO4A9qgOWLhGqnKQdgpKVHaDmChQsvpSiGWiHV19SNaDRCZKA8MOUBPnZIMAbhAe6MBQSoMQSJgA5MDzi8sgAIz6JIbCIWBZLR4gABMgKYMSq7U6wG6vVUQxGY3Ok1k01m33BUAAXvo8sCdFtEcioH00aM+BcjFdbvdHs9Xh8vmDlv0AbUmJtOY9+tDeYg4RYgA), it is not. Why is the behavior different? How can I get the type helper `Check` to behave correctly?

Comment: Please include the details that are currently hidden away in the link.  Three reasons: People shouldn't have to go off-site to help you; some sites are blocked for some users; and links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future.

Comment: Fundamentally, though, a conditional type acting on a generic type parameter becomes a [distributive conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types).

Comment: You're asking "why", not to fix it, so I'm not posting an answer, but defining Check as `type Check<P, Q> = [P] extends [Q] ? true : false` seems to do what you want, meaning @T.J.Crowder is completely right